# Сокет клиент - сервер

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Вопрос возможно глупый. Начал вникать в создание сокет клиента под андроид. Нашел статьи где описывается процесс отправки сообщения с телефона на сервер. Можно ли сделать что бы в качестве сервера выступало другое андроид устройство? Подскажите где можно почитать по этому поводу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Плохая идея. Во-первых, в общем случае мобилка имеет или приватный IP-адрес за NAT'ом или динамический адрес. В первом случае шанса подключиться к серверу нет вообще, а во втором нужен dynamic dns, чтобы клиент знал куда подключаться. Во-вторых, постоянно запущенное приложение ожидающее соединений будет высаживать батарею с неприятно большой скоростью. Наконец, это не безопасно.

Comment: Это понятно, но мне интересна сама процедура, понятное дело что практического применения это не найдет

Comment: Процедура неотличима от любого другого tcp/udp-сервера на Java.